# Why recommend ctx as the first parameter? Is stdlib really consistent about it?

Tags: http, go, backend, go-context

As the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/context) said

> Do not store Contexts inside a struct type; instead, pass a Context explicitly to each function that needs it. The Context should be the first parameter, typically named ctx

but I found, in the typical http request handle function, a `http.Request` object has `.Context()` method can retrieve the context which http request associate with.

So why recommend to use context as the first parameter in these functions? Is that reasonable in this situation?

---

I know that is not an absolute rule. But I want to know why the `HandlerFunc` is `func(ResponseWriter, *Request)` instead of `func(context.Context, ResponseWriter, *Request)`.

Apparently `HandlerFunc` breaks this recommendation.

Comment: The recommendation is a good one, stick to it. Note that for package http the Context hat to be retrofitted without breaking compatibility. Nothing to see here.

Comment: It's a convention. Like "error first callback" in node.

Comment: @Volker So you mean the reason why `.Context()` was added  just for not to break compatibility? That's not a best practice?

Comment: Yes and this **is** best practice. Breaking a guaranteed compatibility promise would be awful practice.

Comment: `req.Context()` is nothing to do with breaking backwards-compatibility? the request stores a context so that you can retrieve it whenever you like (given `http.Request` is a value object in this sense)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As described in the documentation you quoted above, `ctx` should be a (*very*) common argument for many functions. This is similar to the way many functions return an `error`. The best place for a common argument/return value is either as the first, or last in a list.  (Arguably, Go could have chosen to make `error` always be the first return value--I won't discuss that here).

Since [variadic](https://gobyexample.com/variadic-functions) variables may *only* be the last in the list of function arguments, this leaves the only option for a common argument to be the first one.

I expect this is why `ctx` is always first.

This pattern is often seen with other variables in Go (and other languages) as well. Any time a common variable is used by a set of related functions, that common variable often comes first in the argument list (or possibly second, after `ctx`).

---

Contrary to the advice you quoted, there are libraries that store `ctx` in a struct, rather than passing it around as the first argument. These are usually (always?) libraries which had to be retro-fitted to use `ctx`, long after the library contract was set in stone (by the Go 1.x compatibility guarantee).

Generally, you should follow the advice to pass `ctx` as the first argument, for any new work.

Comment: Thank you, as a newcomer the difference in `http` package really make me confused

Comment: Reasons for not storing contexts in a struct are explained in a more recent post on the official blog: https://go.dev/blog/context-and-structs